# Div's are being generated dynamically and even the (obj.search) fetches the data but nothing is being displayed in it. How do i display the data?

Tags: javascript, dom

JS doesn't display the output

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.Search.length; i++){ 
   var divTag = document.createElement("div");
      divTag.id = "div"+i;
      divTag.className = "list";
      document.getElementById('div'+i).innerHTML+=obj.Search[i].Title+obj.Search[i].Year;
}
```

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LtzM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You missed adding the newly created element to the DOM. Example:

```
document.getElementById("yourDivContainer").appendChild(divTag);
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mbpfgm49/

Comment: did that document.getElementById("id01").appendChild(divTag); .... stil wont work . Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example? Seeing the markup would really help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That is why I asked him to provide one in his question.

Answer (score 0):

[You need to append your div tags to some element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) (e.g: body), to make text appear on page

```js
// Let's create some sample data
var obj = {
  Search: []
}

var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
for (var i = currentYear - 10; i <= currentYear; i++) {
  obj.Search.push({
    Title: 'Test',
    Year: i
  })
}

// Here goes your code fixed
for (var i = 0; i < obj.Search.length; i++) {
  var divTag = document.createElement("div");
  divTag.id = "div" + i;
  divTag.className = "list";
  divTag.innerHTML = obj.Search[i].Title + ' ' + obj.Search[i].Year;
  document.body.appendChild(divTag);
}
```

Comment: i did that but i didnt work ... but i looked at your work and i learnt to use "divTag.HTML". Thanks for the help. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to add the element to the DOM.

More basically, it is an anti-pattern to construct IDs for elements and use those as the primary means for referring to elements, by means of calling `getElementById` at every turn. I guess this approach is one of the many lingering after-effects of the jQuery epidemic.

Instead, keep references to elements directly in JS where possible, and use them directly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.Search.length; i++){ 
  var divTag = document.createElement("div");
  divTag.className = "list";
  parent.appendChild(divTag);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  INSERT ELEMENT
  divTag.innerHTML+=obj.Search[i].Title+obj.Search[i].Year;
  ^^^^^^ REFER TO ELEMENT DIRECTLY
}
```

To be absolutely pedantically correct, what you are creating is not a "tag", it's an "element". The element is the DOM object. The "tag" is the `div` which characterizes the element type.